# Jira Python API to insert comment with WIKI formatting

Tags: python-jira

While using jira python module to add comments, is there a possibility to insert comments using WIKI markup?

I noticed some example showed REST API calls with representation:wiki can do this.

But I noticed current python Jira only supports plain text as comments. Is this a limitation or I am missing something?

I checked jira [source code](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/master/jira/client.py#L1639) and noticed data is represented as dictionary and also being dumped using json.dumps, I tried pushing body as dict "{'storage': {'value': '== Activity:  == error-rate-percentage-is-at-acceptable-limits .. Started', 'representation': 'wiki'}}"

But got below error back from Jira API call I guess

```
[2019-12-02 01:07:22 DEBUG] [__init__:386] Before-control 'jira-integration' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chaoslib/control/__init__.py", line 377, in apply_controls
    settings=settings)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>>/python3.7/site-packages/chaoslib/control/python.py", line 147, in apply_python_control
    func(context=context, **arguments)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>>/python3.7/site-packages/<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/controls/jira/tickets.py", line 220, in before_activity_control
    add_comment(os.environ["SUB_TASK_TICKET"], content_as_wiki(formatting.format_as_heading2("Activity: ") + str(context["name"]) + " .. Started"))
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>>/python3.7/site-packages/<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/controls/jira/tickets.py", line 58, in add_comment
    test = JIRA_CLIENT.add_comment(issue, comment)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/python3.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 126, in wrapper
    result = func(*arg_list, **kwargs)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/python3.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1367, in add_comment
    url, data=json.dumps(data)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/python3.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 154, in post
    return self.__verb('POST', url, **kwargs)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/python3.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 147, in __verb
    raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "<<HIDDEN BY ME>>/python3.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 57, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://<<HIDDEN BY ME>>>
    text: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: com.enhancera.auditor.common.filter.RestReadingServletRequest$1@4e08280a; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.rest.json.beans.CommentJsonBean["body"])
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create a comment using markup by passing a string formatted according to the documentation [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all). For a test I created an issue and added a comment to add a two column 1 row (+ header row) table with:

```
comment = jira.add_comment(issue, "||header1||header2||\n|one|two|")
```

Which produced:

[image]

Make sure to wrap your comment string in double quotes.